# Implementing a version of "how-many" function, sensitive to isearch-filter-predicate

Tags: replace, isearch-filter-predicate

I want to build a version of the `how-many` function that is sensitive to `isearch-filter-predicate`.

To achieve this, I had to first build a version of `re-search-forward` that obeys `isearch-filter-predicate`:

```el
(defun re-search-forward-ifp (REGEXP &optional BOUND NOERROR COUNT)
  "Modified version of `search-forward-regexp' that
    filters (skips) matches according to `isearch-filter-predicate'."

  (let ((POINT (point)))
    (catch 'filtered
      (while (search-forward-regexp REGEXP BOUND NOERROR COUNT)
        (let ((B (match-beginning 0))
              (E (match-end 0)))
          (when (funcall isearch-filter-predicate B E)
            (throw 'filtered (point)))))
      (goto-char POINT)
      nil)))
(defalias 'search-forward-regexp-ifp 're-search-forward-ifp)
```

Now, since the definition of `how-many` in `replace.el` is as follows:

```el
(defun how-many (regexp &optional rstart rend interactive)
  "..."
  (interactive
   (keep-lines-read-args "How many matches for regexp"))
  (save-excursion
    (if rstart
        (if rend
            (progn
              (goto-char (min rstart rend))
              (setq rend (max rstart rend)))
          (goto-char rstart)
          (setq rend (point-max)))
      (if (and interactive (use-region-p))
          (setq rstart (region-beginning)
                rend (region-end))
        (setq rstart (point)
              rend (point-max)))
      (goto-char rstart))
    (let ((count 0)
          (case-fold-search
           (if (and case-fold-search search-upper-case)
               (isearch-no-upper-case-p regexp t)
             case-fold-search)))
      (while (and (< (point) rend)
                  (re-search-forward regexp rend t))
        ;; Ensure forward progress on zero-length matches like "^$".
        (when (and (= (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
                   (not (eobp)))
          (forward-char 1))
        (setq count (1+ count)))
      (when interactive (message (ngettext "%d occurrence"
                                           "%d occurrences"
                                           count)
                                 count))
      count)))
```

I want to define a function named `how-many-ifp` that calls `re-search-forward-ifp` instead of `re-search-forward`.

I mean something like:

```el
(defun how-many-ifp (regexp &optional rstart rend interactive)
  "Modified version of `how-many' that filters (skips) matches
    according to `isearch-filter-predicate'."
    (interactive
     (keep-lines-read-args "How many matches for regexp"))
    ;; Pseudocode:
    ;; (let ((re-search-forward re-search-forward-ifp))

    (how-many regexp rstart rend interactive))
```

In practice, I need the symbol `re-search-forward` to call the function `re-rearch-forward-ifp` only within my definition. How can I do it?

I'm open to alternative solutions too.

**EDIT.** I just realized that the `re-search-forward-ifp` definition calls `re-search-forward` (Its alias `search-forward-regexp`). So I think that what I asked for is not possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue of recursively redefining `re-search-forward`, I thought of creating a copy of the function to use for defining `re-search-forward-ifp`.

**Edit.** I rewrote my code like this:

```el
;; I need a copy of `re-search-forward' because it will be temporary adviced in
;; `how-many-ifp' and `occur-ifp' functions:
(defalias 're-search-forward-copy
  (symbol-function 're-search-forward)
  "Copy of `re-search-forward'")

(defun re-search-forward-ifp (REGEXP &optional BOUND NOERROR COUNT)
  "Modified version of `search-forward-regexp' that filters (skips) matches
according to `isearch-filter-predicate'."
  (let ((POINT (point)))
    (catch 'filtered
      (while (re-search-forward-copy REGEXP BOUND NOERROR COUNT)
        (let ((B (match-beginning 0))
              (E (match-end 0)))
          (when (funcall isearch-filter-predicate B E)
            (throw 'filtered (point)))))
      (goto-char POINT)
      nil)))
(defalias 'search-forward-regexp-ifp 're-search-forward-ifp)

(defun override-re-search-forward (orig-fun &rest args)
  "Temporary advice the `re-search-forward' function, overriding it with
`re-search-forward-ifp' to make it sensitive to `isearch-filter-predicate'"
  (unwind-protect
      (progn
        (advice-add 're-search-forward :override #'re-search-forward-ifp)
        (apply orig-fun args))
    (advice-remove 're-search-forward #'re-search-forward-ifp)))

(defalias 'how-many-ifp
  (symbol-function 'how-many)
  "Copy of the `how-many' function (to be) adviced to obey to
`isearch-filter-predicate'")
(defalias 'count-matches-ifp 'how-many-ifp)

(advice-add 'how-many-ifp :around #'override-re-search-forward)
```

I don't know if advicing a function to advice a function inside it is a good idea but it seem to work.

**Edit 2.** Unfortunately, this didn't turn out to be a good idea! By modifying `re-search-forward` within `how-many` using an advice/override, this function (`re-search-forward`) also gets altered within the definitions of certain predicates like, for instance, `texmathp` provided by `AUCTeX`.